# Number of seconds in "HH:MM:SS"

Tags: java, string, parsing

What's the best way to get the number of seconds in a string representation like "hh:mm:ss"?

Obviously Integer.parseInt(s.substring(...))  * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(...))  * 60 + Integer.parseInt(s.substring(...)) works.

But I don't want to test that, and reinvent the wheal, I expect there is a way to use  DateTimeFormat or other classes from standard libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [pakores](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222851/pakore) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206473/number-of-seconds-in-hhmmss/3206580#3206580):

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date reference = dateFormat.parse("00:00:00");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(string);
    long seconds = (date.getTime() - reference.getTime()) / 1000L;
```

`reference` is used to compensate for different timezones and there is no problem with daylight saving time because SimpleDateFormat does NOT use the actual date, it return the Epoc date (January 1st, 1970 = no DST).

Simplifying (not much):

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("01:00:10");
    long seconds = date.getTime() / 1000L;
```

but I would still have a look at Joda-Time...

Comment: thanks! and thanks everyone. Top stuff! Using a ref, of course.

Answer (score 3):

An original way:
The `Calendar` version (updated with the suggestions in the comments):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = dateFormat.parse(string);
//Here you can do manually date.getHours()*3600+date.getMinutes*60+date.getSeconds();
//It's deprecated to use Date class though.
//Here it goes an original way to do it.
Calendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
time.setTime(date);
time.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
time.set(Calendar.YEAR,1970); //Epoc year
time.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.JANUARY); //Epoc month
time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); //Epoc day of month
long seconds = time.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
```

Disclaimer: I've done it by heart, just looking at the documentation, so maybe there is a typo or two.

Comment: not sure if it is a problem in that case, but I remember having trouble with timezones doing something similar.

Comment: This was the best answer but it still didn't work for me, unfortunately there is a smallish difference (about 300 seconds) to the real number and I don't where that comes from.

Try the solution above with "00:00:10".

Thanks a lot anyway, cheers.

Comment: I'll try it in 12h. I don't have a dev env right now. 300 seconds is a lot! Can you post the samples that you tried, the result, and the expected result?

Comment: 300 seconds? the error should be exactly 31 DAYS  +/- the time difference to UTC!
@pakore - You used 1 for month that is february, better use the Calendar constant `JANUARY` (or zero). And time is interpreted as being in the local timezone, `getTimeInMillis` returns UTC milliseconds. (The above code does not compile, missing an 'l' in `getTimeInMillis`...)

Comment: worst, in the first code, the Date will be in year 3870, seconds will be a very big number!!! `setYear` adds 1900 to the passed number, maybe one of the reasons for being deprecated...

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix it with your suggestions Carlos Heuberger. As I said I don't have a dev env right now so I can't try the code, I posted it by heart. Thanks for the tips though :)

Answer (score 1):

joda-time is 1 options. infact i prefer that library for all date manipulations. I was going thru the java 5 javadoc and found this enum class which is simple and useful for you. java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit. look at the convert(...) methods. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html